# Recount SQL auto increment ID while keeping the other columns intact

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I have a table like this

| ID | NAME |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | MICHAEL |
| 2 | JORDAN |
| 5 | DONALD |
| 7 | JAYCE |
| 8 | ROY |
| 11 | JOHN |
| 16 | DOE |

Is there a way to recount the ID from the beggining so there is a sequel and keeping the others columns intact to be like this:

| ID | NAME |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | MICHAEL |
| 2 | JORDAN |
| 3 | DONALD |
| 4 | JAYCE |
| 5 | ROY |
| 6 | JOHN |
| 7 | DOE |

Thank you!

Comment: You can fetch your records with PHP, check the smallest `free ID`, check the next smallest `filled ID`. update set `filled ID = free ID` and continue the check from the next smallest `free ID`

Comment: it is not necessary to sequential ids

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `MySQL` version supports window function, you could use `ROW_NUMBER`.

Suppose you have the following table:

```
create table test(
ID int NOT NULL ,
NAME VARCHAR (25)
);

insert into test values 
(1,'MICHAEL'),
(2,'JORDAN'),
(5,'DONALD'),
(7,'JAYCE'),
(8,'ROY'),
(11,'JOHN'),
(16,'DOE');
```

Using row_number would give:

```
select ID,NAME, row_number() over(order by ID ASC ) as rownum
from test
```

> Result:
>
> ```
> ID    NAME    rownum
> 1   MICHAEL     1
> 2   JORDAN      2
> 5   DONALD      3
> 7   JAYCE       4
> 8   ROY         5
> 11  JOHN        6
> 16  DOE         7
> ```

Now, create another table `test2`.

```
create table test2(
ID int NOT NULL ,
NAME VARCHAR (25)
);
```

We can use `INSERT INTO SELECT`:

```
INSERT INTO test2( ID, NAME )
  WITH cte AS (
            select ID,NAME, row_number() over(order by ID ASC ) as rownum
            from test t1
  )
  SELECT rownum,NAME
  FROM cte;

select * from test2;
```

> Result:
>
> ```
> ID    NAME
> 1 MICHAEL
> 2 JORDAN
> 3 DONALD
> 4 JAYCE
> 5 ROY
> 6 JOHN
> 7 DOE
> ```

See [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ef3cf09b304df91005d9d3817b385053)